# Get context attribute value from console

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, console.log

I'm reading with dev. tools console with this code `$('#basis > td')[1]` this code line: `<td class="EURO" context="11.84689" align="right">€ 11,85</td>`

With `$('#basis > td')[1].textContent` i read the content of `<td></td>`, also `€ 11,85`.

How can i read the value of `context`? - i want to get `11.84689`, but i can't find anywhere, how to fetch context attribute value...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
$(document).find('td')[0].getAttribute('context');
```

or

```
$('#basis').find('td')[0].getAttribute('context');
```

Comment: спасибо, работает. как в 97% случаев, проблема была в синтаксисе.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has a [function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the attributes of elements

```
console.log( $('#basis td:first-child').attr('context') );
```

Comment: get just `Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[1].attr is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

I changed your question a little bit to illustrate on how you can retrieve multiple context values. I take that you were using > in an attempt to retrieve more values. Please try this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="basis">
    <td class="EURO" context="11.84689" align="right">€ 11,85</td>
    <td class="EURO" context="12.84689" align="right">€ 12,85</td>
    <td class="EURO" context="13.84689" align="right">€ 13,85</td>
    <td class="EURO" context="14.84689" align="right">€ 14,85</td>
    <td class="EURO" context="15.84689" align="right">€ 15,85</td>
</table>

<script>
    $('#basis td:first').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('context'));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks - but here i get the values from all TDs, but i neead only the value from the first TD, like i express with `$('#basis > td')[1]`

Comment: If that answer helped, please don't hesitate to choose your best answer.

Comment: with `$('#basis td:first').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('context'));
    });` i get the whole dom tree into console